# How to download created CSV file in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a JSON data in php and now needs to download it when button clicked. Below are the my code

```
function exportPosts($array, $filename, $delimiter){
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'";');
    $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    // save the column headers
    fputcsv($f, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3', 'Column 4', 'Column 5'));
    // Sample data. This can be fetched from mysql too
    $data = array(
        array('Data 11', 'Data 12', 'Data 13', 'Data 14', 'Data 15'),
        array('Data 21', 'Data 22', 'Data 23', 'Data 24', 'Data 25'),
        array('Data 31', 'Data 32', 'Data 33', 'Data 34', 'Data 35'),
        array('Data 41', 'Data 42', 'Data 43', 'Data 44', 'Data 45'),
        array('Data 51', 'Data 52', 'Data 53', 'Data 54', 'Data 55')
    );

    foreach ($data as $line) {
        fputcsv($f, $line,$delimiter);
    }
    fseek($f, 0);
    // tell the browser it's going to be a csv file
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');

    echo readfile($f);
}
```

Function call

```
exportPosts($posts, $filename = "export.csv", $delimiter=",");
```

above function is not working. Please help me to get out of this problem

Comment: "Is not working" how? Did you investigated what is sent and recievied over http? Post your findings.+

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Content-Disposition` header. Add it below your `header('Content-Type: application/csv');`

Code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
```